# Display image in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I am trying to develop a SPA. In this regard I am using vue.js 2 in front end and Laravel 5.5 API in back end. Now I would like to display images in front end. I wrote below code in HTML

```
<img :src="/images/addressObj.image"/>
```

Where should I put images in Laravel and how can I access that image in vue.js ?

Comment: is `addressObj` the variable in Vue instance?

Comment: yes. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here it's that you are not using properly the :src attr, :src spects a string as value, don't let the double quotes confuse you, between the double quotes you have to place your formatted string, notice that if use `:src="www.google.com/size"` the img will try to find the url `www.google.com/size` instead `www.google.com/350x150` or if you try `www.google.com/{{size}}` the img will try to find `www.google.com/%7B%/Bsize%7D%7D` (size it's a var that comes from the example below)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      size: '350x150',
      size2: '350x400'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <button @click="size = '350x150'">Size 350x150</button>
  <button @click="size = '350x200'">Size 350x200</button>
  <!-- notice the single quotes -->
  <img :src="'http://via.placeholder.com/' + size" />
  <hr />
  <button @click="size2 = '350x400'">Size2 350x400</button>
  <button @click="size2 = '350x300'">Size2 350x300</button>
  <!-- here with string interpolation -->
  <img :src="`http://via.placeholder.com/${size2}`" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is a `.vue` or `.js` file,

```
<img :src="`/images/${addressObj.image}`"/>
```

I assume that you have correctly done the necessary stuff for the variable `addressObj`.

Comment: Thanks @Ru Chern Chong. I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ru Chern Chong. Where should I put images in Laravel ?

Comment: I have no idea why you want to do there. Use the Laravel Storage helper?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use Laravel Storage helper.

Comment: Go with that. I think it’s really useful and easy to implement. If you’re using AWS, they have the integration already albeit your client secrets.

Comment: Thanks @Ru Chern Chong for your reply. I am trying to access like this `http://localhost:8000/assets/images/default.jpg` .But I can't see the image in the browser. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit tricky. You have to look at the `Storage` helper documentation on Laravel and follow accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

well, as u have dynamic source binding, u have to require each image.

so u just should do like that:

```
<img :src='require(`./images/${addressObj.image}`)'>
```